# Track count of app launch in android library for analytics

Tags: android, count, analytics, launch

I am developing an Android library for analytics. I have created a method to get all device data. Application class of the app will call this library method.

I want to track app launch count also. I tried to use the same method but Application class does not get called every time. For first app launch, got call in application class but when I tried to exit app using back press and launch again, I did not get any call.

Last option for me to track launch count is ask application to add one more call in on-create of launcher activity but is there any better way? How firebase and other analytic libraries implements this?

Answer (score 0):

When you close your app by doing back press again and again. It pushes the application in background but doesn't kill it. So the application class is not initiated again. So this is not treated as App Launch.

App Launch is triggered when the user kills the app or the OS kills the app in background due to limitation of resources.

So, what you have done is fine...but if you want to beyond this you would need to implement your own logic like you mentioned (using onCreate of activity)